# How to change background color of button on press in kivy?

Tags: kivy

My app has a single button with a default background color. I just want to change its background color to another color on `on_press` event. You may consider it similar to visited and non-visited hyperlinks of html ie when a linked is clicked, it changes its color.

My attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

from random import random
from random import choice
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_string("""
<Highest>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            text: "Hi"
            on_press: root.new()
""")

class Highest(Screen):
    def new(self):
        self.background_color=(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)


# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Highest(name='Highest'))

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

But nothing happens on on_press

---

@inclement

Actually, i tried to minimized my problem.

What i actually need is to give different colors on different conditions based on a variable

```
class Highest(Screen):
    def new(self):
        if(a==5):
            self.background_color=(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        else:
            self.background_color=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

so i want impementation in my class Highest. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to keep it within a function, you could also add an id to the button and then change it from the Highest instance.

```
Builder.load_string("""
<Highest>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            id: button_one
            text: "Hi"
            on_press: root.new()
""")
```

Then you can reference the id to change the color...

```
class Highest(Screen):
    def new(self):
        self.ids['button_one'].background_color = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
```

Answer (score 9):

> But nothing happens on on_press

It actually does, you set the background_color attribute of your Highest instance - but you don't see anything happen because it doesn't use background_color for anything.

You could instead just have:

```
on_press: self.background_color = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

By putting this in the Button rule, `self` refers to the button instance you actually want to change.

Answer (score 4):

I know this was asked a while ago, but when I tried playing along with the above suggestions my buttons never changed back to their original color.  What I ended up doing to fix the issue was add the on_release to change it to whatever color I wanted:

```
on_press: self.background_color = (0, 1, 0, 1)
on_release: self.background_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
```

Figured if I was having this issue, somebody might want to know about this

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to change its background color to another color on on_press event.

I actually ran into similar problem. I am going all idiomatic python for kivy. I use a callback function `on_press`.

```
Class MainWindow(ScreenManager):
    <..code to add screens and add widget to screen...>
    <...>

    def add_button(self):
        Button(id='button1', text='Hello %d'%i, size_hint=(0.2,0.2),
                              on_press=self.callback, background_color=[1,0,0,1])
```

In my callback,

```
    def callback(self, value):
            print '%s pressed.'%value
            print value.id
            value.background_color= (0,1,0,1)
```

Thats it. This will change the background color of the button from red to green.

> What i actually need is to give different colors on different conditions based on a variable

You can implement that logic in your callback.. pass `a` to the callback (I would suggest using partial for doing that)

ps. I also see you are using a separate class for Screen but that shouldn't matter here