# Kivy - Change the color of a button after being pressed?

Tags: python, kivy

I have two buttons on my application, and they are both purple with white text. When the button is pressed, I wanted the color to change to a dark purple. Clearly there is something simple I am missing, as my code doesn't work like I would expect it to.

```
       Button:
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex("#752db5")
            text: 'Sign Up'
            size_hint: .3, .3
            padding: 3, 1
            font_name: 'Roboto-Medium'
            background_color_down: utils.get_color_from_hex("#5b238d")
```

Comment: Is the button the correct color otherwise? Because `background_color_down` expects a [image resource](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_down). Not sure how picky they are about colors != images. But that might be it otherwise. If that's the case, you could do `btn1.bind(state=callback)` and in your callback function handle these things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change background color of button on press in kivy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970964/how-to-change-background-color-of-button-on-press-in-kivy)

Comment: Have you checked the other question's accepted answer? Do you receive an error message?

Comment: @Alex_P I personally think mine is different, but I could be wrong. I was trying to achieve this in a kv file alone

Comment: @Torxed There's no function to achieve this in a kv file? I thought it was pretty simple and wouldn't require any python logic. But yes it is the correct purple when it is not being pressed. I just wanted to darken it when clicked because when pressed, it is a dark blue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, my favorite way to do something like this is to make a new class called `LabelButton` in a .py file and have it inherit kivy's `ButtonBehavior` and `Label` classes. Then the coloring is done by using the `LabelButton`'s canvas, and you can still use the `on_release` function like any normal button because you've inherited `ButtonBehavior`.

Changing the background color of the canvas can be done by a really nice trick. See my example.

in your .py file include this code:

```
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class LabelButton(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    pass
```

Then in your .kv file you can reference the LabelButton class:

```
LabelButton:
    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgb: (1,0,0,1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0,1,0,1) # Color is red if button is not pressed, otherwise color is green
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: 10,20,30,40 # Play with these if you want smooth corners for your button
    text: "I am a LabelButton"
    color: (0,0,1,1) # text color is blue
    on_release:
        print("I have been clicked")
```

Comment: p.s. to make your label look even more button-like, you could underline the text. To do that you would change the `text` to `text: [u]I am a LabelButton[/u]`, then make sure to add another property `markup: True` to make kivy understand your `[u]` and `[/u]` tags. Also works for bold font (`[b] some text [/b]`) or italics (`[i] some text [/i]`)

Comment: Thanks again Erik. You're always a help. Looking forward to the videos as well