# Kivy button on_press background colour is not changing

Tags: python, user-interface, raspberry-pi, kivy

Kivy Button component on_press colors are not working in Kivy 2.0.0.

I check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970964/how-to-change-background-color-of-button-on-press-in-kivy) and followed the answers, however, those answers didn't resolve the problem that I am facing.

My UI kv file button component code

```
Button:
    text: Settings
    background_color: (.3, 2.15, .96, 1)
    on_press: self.background_color = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    on_press: root.on_settings_click()
    on_press: self.background_color = (.3, 2.15, .96, 1)
```

Python code for button response

```
class SettingsMenu(Panel):
    def on_general_settings_click(self):
        self._parent.show_new_panel(GeneralSettings(self._parent))
```

EDIT:

I used on_release also doesn't make any change on the UI button component. Is there anything else I'm missing here?

```
    on_press: self.background_color = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    on_press: root.on_general_settings_click()
    on_release: self.background_color = (.3, 2.15, .96, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `background_color` with `on_press` works in Kivy 2.0.0. But it may not show up in your GUI if the changes happen too quickly. Changing the `background_color` twice in the `on_press` event response will likely just show its last setting, so consider also using `on_release`. The other thing to keep in mind is that `background_color` is just a multiplier on the `background_normal` and `background_down` images. If you want a pure color for the `normal` or `down` states, then you must set `background_normal` and/or `background_down` to `''`. Here is an example using these principles:

```
Button:
    text: 'Settings'
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: ''
    background_color: (1, 0, 0, 1)
    on_press: self.background_color = (0, 1, 0, 1.0)
    on_press: root.on_settings_click()
    on_release: self.background_color = (0, 0, 1, 1)
```

Comment: I tried on_release also that didn't reflect when running the UI at Kivy 2.0.0.   `on_release: self.background_color = (.3, 2.15, .96, 1)`

Comment: Your change seems to work for me. What exactly are you expecting to see?

Comment: I just want to add color during on_press of the button to get feedback button is pressed.  I'm using Kivy 2.0.0. When I press the button it takes me to a new view and color is not changed when the button is pressed.

Comment: What you want is exactly what I see (running Kivy 2.0.0). Perhaps you should post a [mcve].